# Changing date format for labels in ArcGis Pro with label expression?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro, python-parser, datetime

I am trying to use an expression to convert my date field to a simple %d,%b,%Y format. Right now it is in "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %z"

How do I do it properly using Python to do this in ArcGIS Pro?

Q&As from ArcMap have given me errors.

My labels are coming from my [Date] field.

Here's one example of a code I tried -

```
def FindLabel ( [Date]  ):
  return str(datetime.datetime.strptime([Date],"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %z").date())
```

and I got this error:

[image]

My labels look this :

[image]

I also tried this code:

```
from datetime import datetime  
def FindLabel ( [Date] ):  
  d = datetime.strptime([Date], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %z')  
  return d.strftime('%d, %b %Y')
```

[image]

Comment: What type is your ‘Date’ field?   Text?  Date?

Comment: Please put error messages in your question body as text, not image. Images are not legible on all devices or free-text searchable.

Comment: The field is 'Date' format

Comment: The reason I put the errors as pictures is because the format they appear in the labeling expression window in ArcGIS Pro does not allow for them to be selected. If others have a suggestion for copying the errors with your cursor in the labeling expression area - please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late but just in case you still have the same issue, the Python code I used was the following:

```
def FindLabel ( [Fecha]  ):
  return str(datetime.datetime.strptime([Fecha],"%d/%m/%Y").date())
```

You could change the field "Fecha" for "date", I used it that way cause my fields are in Spanish.

Comment: Thank you! If I ever need to solve this issue again I will give your solution a try